# $\mathbb C P^1\cong (D^2\times\{1\}+ D^2\times \{-1\})\big /_\sim $

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space

I need to proove a bigger result that $\mathbb C P^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.
For that I have already showed $$S^2\cong (D^2\times\{1\}+ D^2\times \{-1\})\big /_\sim$$ where $(z,1)\sim (z,-1) \iff z \in S^1$ and identity anywhere else.
Now I'm searching for two subsets in $\mathbb C P^1$ which union is homeomorphic to $D^2\times\{1\}+D^2\times \{-1\}\big /_\sim$.
I tried to partition lines $[a:b]$ in $\mathbb C^2$ in such sets where either $[a:b]=[1:c]$ or $[a:b]=[0:d]$, but second one is to "small" to be homeomorphic.
I need some hints guys.

Comment: First, we may assume $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$ (or, depending on your definition of $\mathbb{C}P^n$, this may automatically be true).  Now...Hint:  Think about $|a|^2 \leq 1/2$ and $|a|^2\geq 1/2$ separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method does work.

Take $$ D^2_{\rm first} = \{ [1 : z] \in \mathbb {CP}^1 :  | z | \leq 1 \}$$ $$ D^2_{\rm second} =  \{ [w : 1]  \in \mathbb {CP}^1 : | w | \leq 1 \}$$
and identify the boundary points like this:
$$[1 :e^{i\theta}] \in D^2_{\rm first}  \ \sim \ [ e^{-i\theta} : 1] \in D^2_{\rm second} \  \ \ \ {\rm for \ all \ } \theta \in [0, 2\pi) $$

It is then immediate that
$$ \mathbb {CP}^1 \cong \left( D^2_{\rm first} \coprod D^2_{\rm second} \right) / \sim  \ \cong \ S^2. $$

Comment: I admire your answer. Although it appears that you have directly identified $D^2_{\rm first}\subset \mathbb C P^1$ with $D^2\subset \mathbb R^2$, but that's okay I guess?
I think I got it, thank you!

Comment: Yes, we can say that $\mathbb {CP}^1 = D_{\rm first}^2 \cup D_{\rm second}^2$. But by introducing the equivalence relation, we are spelling out how the two disks are joined together, and this is important. And yes, I'm identifying $D_{\rm first}^2 \subset \mathbb {CP}^1$ with the disk $D^2 := \{ z \in \mathbb C  : |z | \leq 1 \} \subset \mathbb C$, which is obvious homeomorphic to the disk $D^2 := \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq 1 \} \subset \mathbb R^2$.